How to measure inductance of a coil? I tried finding the time constant and then using it to find L but the value does not match with LCR meter
I have built a simple RL circuit connected to a 12 Vdc power supply through a switch. The resistance value of resistor is 159.5 Ω and the internal resistance of my inductive coil is 160 Ω.
At the instant when the switch is closed, I capture the Voltage waveform across the inductive coil through an oscilloscope. When the voltage VL drops to 37% of the initial voltage value 12 V, I measure the time constant and calculate inductance by the formula L = time constant * R.
When the switch is closed the voltage drops from 12 V till it gets stable at around 6.4 V. I measure the time constant when the voltage is 8.472 V ([0.37 * (12-6.4)]+6.4). The time constant comes around 380 µs.
L = 380 µs * 159.5 = 60.61 mH
But the LCR meter reads value 90.1 mH.
Can you please point out if I am doing something wrong? Is there any other method you can suggest to check this?
Below is the circuit I have created and the oscilloscope screenshot.


Update 1:
I made changes as suggested by one of the answer:
I changed the power supply to 1 V provided as a square wave pulse from the function generator. I recorded the Voltage waveform across the inductor. Measured the time constant when voltage VL drops to [(0.37 * (initial voltage - voltage value when it gets stable))+ Voltage Value when it gets stable]. Took the value of external resistance into consideration while measuring the inductance value.
L = (time constant) * (R1 + R2) = 140 us * (159.5+158.1) = 45mH [No where near LCR meter reading]

Below is the VL voltage waveform on the oscilloscope


Why not simulate the circuit and then you can see where you are going badly wrong in your theory.

Was the LCR meter (at minimum) open/short compensated before taking the measurement?

Try an AC source instead of a DC source. With the 3-voltage (input voltage, voltage across reference resistor, voltage across DUT) method you can calculate inductance and ESR. Another option would be to measure 2 voltages (input voltage and voltage across DUT) and the phase shift inbetween to arrive at the same result.

LCR meter was not open/short compensated

Add a diode across the inductor, to protect your oscilloscope from the huge voltage spike that the inductor will produce when the switch opens again.
The inductor's own resistance must be accounted for. Total resistance in the loop will be the sum of inductor and external resistances:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Time constant \$\tau\$ will be:
$$ \tau = \frac{L}{R_1 + R_2} $$
You say that the final voltage is 6.4V, which suggests the coil's own resistance is not 160Ω, your external resistance is not 160Ω, or the supply isn't 12V. If all these values were correct, then you'd expect node X to settle at exactly 6V. Something isn't what you think it is.
There's no point quoting more than 2 significant figures for any measurement, since the whole setup has systematic errors everywhere. I see that your initial voltage spike goes well over 12V, perhaps to 13V. It also appears that your scope has a DC offset of +0.6V or so (see the gap between your voltage source at 0V and the yellow zero marker) which you should address before you start to measure, or at least account for in your calculations.
There seems to be "steps" in the waveform, suggesting that resolution is poor. Adjust the timebase and vertical scales on the scope to more appropriate values, so the region of interest fills more of the screen. That will vastly improve measurement accuracy.
Also consider performing the experiment at a lower voltage, say 1V, as the LCR meter does. This will lower maximum current, mitigating the possibility of inductor core saturation.

I did not have a diode on hand but I provided 1 V through a function generator and took into consideration the external resistance value along with the internal resistance to measure inductance. I got an inductance value of 92 mH which is close to what the LCR meter is reading. When I tried using the same setup to measure another coil (45.5 mH, with internal resistance of 79.7 ohm) it gives me a wrong value as compared to LCR meter. Is it possible that the value of the external R should be always similar to the value of the inductors internal R for an accurate measurement of inductance?

@Kinjal I don't know what the best external resistance would be, since I don't know the current limit of your function generator, or at what point your inductor core will saturate.

@Kinjal The LCR meter performs measurements at low current, and at some relatively high frequency (probably 1kHz or more), and the results it provides will depend on parasitic capacitance, core permeability, core losses and other things that depend on frequency. It will report different values at different frequencies. In your experiment external resistance will surely affect results for the same reasons. There are too many variables and sources of error.

@Kinjal if you don't use the diode you will very likely (eventually) damage your oscilloscope doing this.

The problem is that you are ignoring the effect of the inductor resistance. It is significant since it is equal to the external resistor. The inductor is modeled as a series combination of its resistance and an ideal inductor. Your oscilloscope is measuring the voltage across the resistor and the inductor. You can redo your analysis of the circuit to take into account this resistance or you can increase the value of the external resistor so it is much larger than the inductor resistance (say at least 15 kilohms). Also, you should decrease the timebase on the oscilloscope so the waveform of interest occupies more of the screen. This will increase the measurement accuracy.

It could be the capacitance of the circuit is throwing the measurements off. If it's easy I'd do a couple different resistances and frequencies until you get better agreement. Try and eliminate capacitance from the circuit (although this shouldn't be hard since you have such a large inductance, it probably isn't causing the problem).
I would zoom in on the scope an try an get a better measurement also.

I am not changing frequency. I am providing a 12 V DC supply to the circuit.

The measurement of the inductance of a solenoid and its resistance is done using the Maxwell bridge. When the bridge is in equilibrium, that is, when the voltage between nodes 1 and 2 is zero, obtained by varying the capacitance C and the potentiometer R, then the inductance and resistance of the solenoid are given by the two formulas shown in the photo together with the circuit:

